# how can fixed this prve button for slide show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create one slide show with Array. I created the "next" button and this works good.

I tried to fix the "prv" button but I can't. What to do? I tried `imgIndex--;` but its not working.

```js
let downimgs = document.querySelectorAll('.down-imgs img')
let topimg = document.querySelector('.top-img img')
let myImg = document.getElementById('mainimge')
let imgArray = ["img/3-kid.jpeg", "img/men-1.jpg", "img/woamn-1.jpeg", "img/woman-2.jpg"]
let imgIndex = 0;
downimgs.forEach(imgs => {
  imgs.addEventListener('click', () => {
    topimg.src = imgs.src
  })
});

function next() {
  myImg.setAttribute("src", imgArray[imgIndex]);
  imgIndex++;
  if (imgIndex >= imgArray.length) {
    imgIndex = 0
  }
}

// my proplem here .. 
function prv() {

  myImg.setAttribute("src", imgArray[imgIndex - 1]);
  imgIndex--;
  if (imgIndex >= imgArray.length) {
    imgIndex = 3
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  height: 300px;
}

.top-img img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.next,
.prv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next {
  transform: translate(-150px, -50px);
}

.prv {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(150px, -50px);
}

.down-imgs img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.full-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="s.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="full-parent">
    <figure class="top-img">
      <img src="img/3-kid.jpeg" alt="" id="mainimge">
    </figure>
    <div class="down-imgs">
      <img src="img/3-kid.jpeg" class="slide">
      <img src="img/men-1.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="img/woamn-1.jpeg" alt="" class="slide">
      <img src="img/woman-2.jpg" alt="" class="slide">
    </div>
    <span class="next" onclick="next()">&#10095</span>
    <span class="prv" onclick="prv()">&#10094</span>
  </section>

  <script src="s.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a defect in your `prv` function.  You are decrementing imgIndex, but then checking that imgIndex is greater than or equal to the array length.  Instead, you want to check that imgIndex is less than 0, then adjust accordingly.  You will also want to change the order of the boundary check, otherwise you have potential to go out of bounds with `imgArray[imgIndex-1]`.

Based on your code, I believe you want something like:

```
function prv(){
    if (--imgIndex<0){  // if imgIndex leaves imgArray lower bound
        imgIndex = imgArray.length-1;  // wrap imgIndex around to the upper bound of the array
    }
    myImg.setAttribute("src" , imgArray[imgIndex]);
}
```

Comment: ty i fixed this and leraning new something ty ♥

Comment: Glad to help.  Please accept the answer to close out your question.